# php or mysql timestamp off by 7 hours

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

I am currently on some shared hosting and when i use `NOW()` or `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` in my php sql queries the inserted data is 7 hours behind.

Is there something i can do in PHP to correct this?

I have tried

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Dublin');
```

but it didn't seem to make a difference.

OUTPUT:

```
php time: 1347544854 
date: 2012-09-13 14:0054 UTC 
mysql array(3) { 
["zone"]=> string(6) "SYSTEM" 
["utcts"]=> string(19) "2012-09-13 14:00:54" 
["now"]=> string(19) "2012-09-13 07:00:54" 
}
```

Comment: Why not inserting php's `time()` instead of MySQL's `NOW()`. Then `date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Dublin');` (which is a PHP setting) would also make more sense.

Comment: Is the time in php or mysql wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the mysql functions, it's going to use the timezone set in MySQL. You can change the timezone by using this in your query:

```
SET time_zone = 'Europe/Dublin'
```

Comment: tried this: $sql = "SET time_zone = 'Europe/Dublin'"; $stmt = $this->query($sql); nothing happened, doing it wrong?

Comment: Make sure you do this right before every query where you're going to checking the time. It will only last as long as the script does, before reverting back to the server default.

Answer (score 2):

MySQL timezone is different than PHP timezone.

Here is the [MySQL Time Zone Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html), shows you how to set it.

For the lazy:

```
mysql> SET time_zone = timezone;
```

Answer (score 1):

-not an answer, but too long for a comment-
Please try (with the correct credentials for the mysql connection)

```
<?php
echo "php\n";
echo 'time: ', time(), "\n";
echo 'date: ', date('Y-m-d H:is T', time()), "\n";

echo "mysql\n";
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;charset=utf8', 'localonly', 'localonly');
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
foreach( $pdo->query('SELECT @@time_zone as zone, UTC_TIMESTAMP() as utcts, Now() as now', PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row ) {
    foreach( $row as $k=>$v) {
        echo $k, '=', $v, "\n";
    }
}
```

the output should be something like

```
php
time: 1347543592
date: 2012-09-13 15:3952 CEST
mysql
zone=SYSTEM
utcts=2012-09-13 13:39:53
now=2012-09-13 15:39:53
```

please add the output on your machine to your original question...

Comment: The server's timezone is set to utc-7, that would be something like "Amercia/Denver". And your mysql server is configured to use the server's timezone. "Europe/Dublin" on the other hand (currently) is utc+1. Is this your own "personal" server?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12407547/4833 , Matt K's answer should fix it, though you'd have to do it on every connection.